# Copy node module bundle files

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, tsconfig

I am working on an nodejs project and installed a node module that uses webpack to create some bundle files.

After importing the module in my ts file I got a runtime exception in the browser, because obviously I have to add those bundle files to my build directory.

My initial thought was to add a script to my `package.json` file using `mkdir` and `cp` commands to copy the required bundle files into my build directory, but I am not quite sure that this would be the best approach? Or is there another way to automatically add a node module bundle files after installing it?

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2021",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 2,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without more information. There are almost certainly far superior ways but it depends on your own build tools and the specific dependency in question.

Comment: The problem is that there a js file in the installed module that contains `Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });` and the browser throws `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: exports is not defined` so I noticed that I have to add the module generated browser bundles created with webpack in order to avoid that error.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately that doesn't really answer my question which was about your own tool chain

Comment: I am using nodejs and installed diffusion via npm: `npm install diffusion` then while importing the module `import * as diffusion from 'diffusion';` I got in the browser console `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: exports is not defined  at diffusion.js:5:23`

Comment: and I am using tsc to compile ts files, I added the config file to the question

Comment: could you provide the webpack config you use please? I think, you miss the `libraryTarget` in it.
as well as if i remember correctly diffusion depends on whenjs what depends on vertx, and whenjs is not maintained anymore so you will have to create that empty folder under node_modules for vertx (see https://github.com/cujojs/when/issues/482)

Comment: I am not using webpack.  But diffusion however does and it created some bundle files. I though maybe no need to use webpack and re-create the files and simply import them to project build directory.

Comment: I am using now rollup js as module bundler and I added more detailed question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77601193/how-to-configure-rollup-module-bundler-to-create-browser-bundles-for-a-node-modu