# How to configure Rollup module bundler to create browser bundles for a node module

Tags: node.js, typescript, browser, rollupjs

I have a typescript application, after installing the npm package diffusion `npm install diffusion` and then importing it into a ts file `import * as diffusion from 'diffusion';`

I got in the browser's console the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: exports is not defined  at diffusion.js:5:23
```

I am using rollup to create the app bundle files and web-dev-server to start the app.
Those are the configs I am using:
**rollup.config.mjs file**

```
import { createSpaConfig } from '@open-wc/building-rollup';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import merge from 'deepmerge';


const absoluteBaseUrl = 'http://localhost:8000';

const appConfig = merge(
  createSpaConfig({
    outputDir: 'dist',
    nodeResolve: { browser: true, dedupe: ['lit-html'] },
    html: {
      absoluteBaseUrl,
      extractAssets: false,
      minify: false,
    },
    legacyBuild: false,
    developmentMode: true,
    workbox: false,
    injectServiceWorker: false,
  }),
  {
    input: 'index.html',
    plugins: [
      typescript({
        declaration: false,
        sourceMap: false,
        inlineSources: false,
        compilerOptions: {
          target: 'esnext',
        },
      }),
      replace({
        preventAssignment: true,
        include: 'index.html',
      }),
    ],
  }
);


export default [appConfig];
```

**tsconfig.json** (tried to add node_modules/**/* to the include but didn't work  )

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2021",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 2,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
```

}

**web-dev-server.config.mjs**

```
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { esbuildPlugin } from '@web/dev-server-esbuild';


export default {
  appIndex: 'index.html',
  nodeResolve: true,
  plugins: [
    esbuildPlugin({
      ts: true,
      tsconfig: fileURLToPath(new URL('./tsconfig.json', import.meta.url)),
    }),
  ],
};
```

I see that the required module has already some bundle files under : `/node_modules/diffusion/dist`

I am not quite sure how to handle node_modules files, do I have to copy those bundle files into my build directory or do I have to change the rollup config in order to create the necessary bundle files?